# How to read a big sparse matrix in R? (> 2^31-1)

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I am working with a really big mtx (> 2^31-1) in R right now.
Have tried `Matrix::readMM` and `spam::read.MM`. Both warned me that the number of non-zero values exceed the range of integers.

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Maybe package `slam` is able for that size.

Comment: Have you tried any of these strategies? https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/72295_692737b667614d369bd87cb0f51c9a4b.html

Comment: Or the package `spray`.

Comment: You need to give more details.  What id you try with those two commands?  What shape is your matrix?  How many non-zero entries?

Comment: My matrix is 1598708 * 27943 with 2495202255 non-zero entries.

Comment: Will try `slam` and `spary`. Thx!